# How to easily renew PFX certificate?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-renewal

I am using IIS 10 with a variety of SSL certificates installed and bound with SNI.

I now need to renew a wildcard PFX certificate, I would normally Import the new file and manually rebind each site to use the new certificate before deleting the old one but I now have over a hundred sites.

There must be a better way?

I have looked at the Renew functions but they are only for .CER files not .PFX.

As you can see from screenshot, both certificates are imported ok but how best to apply the new one to the existing sites automatically?  Is there a quick and reliable way to upgrade an inuse PFX certificate with a new PFX file?

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with IIS but a `.pfx` is just a certificate with the associated private key bundled together. The certificate being a `.cer`, you should be able to apply renewal functionality to it. Moreover, renewing a `.pfx` seems to imply you're obtaining your private key along with your certificate which is dubious.